# Why aren't violations of Sunday HGV bans being flagged in Germany

Tags: routes, here-api

According to many sources, trucks with gross vehicular weights in excess of 7.5 tonnes are prohibited from travelling on the German road network on Sundays and public holidays from midnight to 22.00.

When I submit a request to the Routing API (v8) for a trip between two sample locations (Munich and Nuremberg) beginning Sunday at 02.00, the response provides a standard travel summary but fails to note that any prohibitions have been breached.

This is in contrast to a sample journey in the UK that violates a time-based prohibition, where a `notices` key details the violation.

Why is a similar `notices` key missing from the German request?

**Germany**

*request*

```
https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?&apikey=<API_KEY>&transportmode=truck&departuretime=2021-04-25t02:00:00z&return=travelSummary,passthrough&origin=48.16549,11.46595&destination=49.45395,11.06725&vehicle=truck&truck[grossweight]=38000
```

*response*

```
{
    "routes": [
    {
        "id": "6dbdd89e-ed04-4a56-89aa-62e62dfa61cb",
        "sections": [
            {
                "id": "a0d6ca33-5c1a-48dd-8a01-6423eccc39b5",
                "type": "vehicle",
                "departure": {
                    "time": "2021-04-25T04:00:00+02:00",
                    "place": {
                        "type": "place",
                        "location": {
                            "lat": 48.16552,
                            "lng": 11.46595
                        },
                        "originalLocation": {
                            "lat": 48.1654899,
                            "lng": 11.4659499
                        }
                    }
                },
                "arrival": {
                    "time": "2021-04-25T06:20:42+02:00",
                    "place": {
                        "type": "place",
                        "location": {
                            "lat": 49.4534,
                            "lng": 11.06675
                        },
                        "originalLocation": {
                            "lat": 49.45395,
                            "lng": 11.06725
                        }
                    }
                },
                "travelSummary": {
                    "duration": 8442,
                    "length": 174153,
                    "baseDuration": 8442
                },
                "transport": {
                    "mode": "truck"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**UK / London Lorry Control Scheme**

*request*

```
https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?&apikey=<API_KEY>&transportmode=truck&departuretime=2021-04-25t02:00:00z&return=travelSummary,passthrough&origin=51.49591,-0.34113&destination=51.50755,-0.12777&vehicle=truck&truck[grossweight]=38000
```

*response*

```
{
    "routes": [
        {
            "id": "aac34e21-3a43-4b57-b985-f280c6468e73",
            "sections": [
                {
                    "id": "2824d260-57f4-4d77-91b9-170865f70dc3",
                    "type": "vehicle",
                    "departure": {
                        "time": "2021-04-25T03:00:00+01:00",
                        "place": {
                            "type": "place",
                            "location": {
                                "lat": 51.4958792,
                                "lng": -0.3413206
                            },
                            "originalLocation": {
                                "lat": 51.49591,
                                "lng": -0.34113
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "arrival": {
                        "time": "2021-04-25T04:18:51+01:00",
                        "place": {
                            "type": "place",
                            "location": {
                                "lat": 51.50755,
                                "lng": -0.12785
                            },
                            "originalLocation": {
                                "lat": 51.5075499,
                                "lng": -0.12777
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "travelSummary": {
                        "duration": 4731,
                        "length": 29791,
                        "baseDuration": 4731
                    },
                    "notices": [
                        {
                            "title": "Violated vehicle restriction.",
                            "code": "violatedVehicleRestriction",
                            "severity": "critical",
                            "details": [
                                {
                                    "type": "restriction",
                                    "cause": "Route violates vehicle restriction",
                                    "maxGrossWeight": 18000,
                                    "timeDependent": true
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "transport": {
                        "mode": "truck"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notices appear only when the Routing API could not find any other routing option without a violation. In other cases, where it is able to find an alternative route without restrictions then it would always provide you that route. Also please note that the truck violations applies mostly only to some highways. So if the route provided is not passing any of those highways with restrictions then also notices will not be provided.

**Route Section Notices**

These notices appear at the section level within a route and generally indicate some issue with the route produced. The majority of these route section notices indicate that the calculated route could not avoid, and thus violates some specific restriction (e.g., violatedVehicleRestriction), or violates a requested option (e.g., violatedAvoidTollRoad).
Attributes